# Astropy: Add Alt & Az to a coordinate object (Skycoord)

Tags: python, coordinates, astropy, cartesian

I have 2 Astropy tables containing Alt/Az coordinates calculated for my local horizon. The Alt & Az are in 2 separate columns.

I want to do something similar to 'match_to_catalog_sky'  to look for matches across the 2 tables but this requires a Skycoord object.

So, how do I form Skycoord objects from each of my Alt/Az pairs in each table?

If I do this (Which I know is wrong) with the pair in the first row of one of the tables:

```
alt = table1[0]['Altitude']
az = table1[0]['Azimuth']   

coord = SkyCoord(alt, az, frame='icrs')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Latitude angle(s) must be within -90 deg <= angle <= 90 deg, got 142.5422410917743 deg
```

because astropy is expecting coordinates in the RA & Dec system.

I added in `representation_type='cartesian'` but that's expecting x, y & z and I only have x & y.

I've totally confused myself now and I'm struggling to piece together a logical solution from the Astropy docs.

Can anyone help?
cheers

Answer (score 2):

Well who's stoopid. Just need to set `frame='altaz'` like this

```
coord = SkyCoord(alt = alt, az = az, frame='altaz')
```